# Plotting phase portrait of saddle node using Nullclines

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

For an $\mathbb{R}^2$ dynamical system, I am wondering how I can proceed to plot the phase portrait of a saddle-node fixed point using only the nullclines. I know how to plot the phase portrait using the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. However, the nullclines are usually faster to find.

Is it possible to infer anything about the stable and unstable manifold knowing only the nullclines and the vector field on them?

Answer (score 0):

A nullcline associated with the state variable $x_1$ is a curve in phase space where the magnitude of the vector field along the $x_1$ direction is zero. Because of this, every nullcline on the plane splits the phase portrait into two regions: one where the vector field points in the positive $x_1$ direction and one where the vector field points in the negative $x_1$ direction.

Using this information, you might be able to deduce the regions where the stable and unstable manifold of the saddle lie within the phase portrait.